# how to make only uppercase variable python

Tags: python

I was looking for some staff in forum, but everything looks pretty complicated or it's making only first letter big and others small and etc.
Is there a way to change only first letter to uppercase ? Something like :

```
test = 'someThing'
anotherTest = test(it will become 'SomeThing')
```

Answer (score 1):

`'someThing'.title()` will downcase the rest of the word, so you need to target the first letter only:

```
>>> var = 'someThing'
>>> print(var.title())
Something
>>> print(var[0].title() + var[1:])
SomeThing
```

Looks complex, I know, but there's no default string operator for this. You can always wrap it in a simple function:

```
def CamelCase(s):
    return s[:1].title() + s[1:]
```

(By using the range `s[:1]`, I avoid an error on the empty string.)

Comment: `.upper()` might be clearer

Comment: I think that's down to individual preference, Chris. For me, using `title()` on a single letter telegraphs the intent of the whole construction, so I consider that clearer.

Comment: agree it's subjective, but to me, `.upper()` is more well known and sufficient, if you want to show intent, `.capitalize()` would seem clearer that `.title()`

Comment: I specifically chose `title()` over `capitalize()` because it's the one I've seen more often in my experience. I rest my case :-)